# Why does installation keep stopping?

Tags: android, flutter

I've been trying to download my flutter app on my physical android phone using android studio. When I press run, it almost automatically stops and the error says "Installation failed due to: 'Invalid File: /appName_android.apk
Failed to launch an application on all devices"
I'm not sure why there's an invalid file because it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

settings>build,execute,deployment>instant run>Enable instant run to hot swap code /resource change on deploy(unchecked this option)

-- OR --

1. build -> clean project
2. build -> rebuild project
3. run project

Comment: hey melisa, i can't find instant run under Build, executions, deployment